mysql-connector-cpp need to build to android NDK
Im trying to build mysql-connector-cpp from git to use at Android arm to connector mysql Server
im trying to compile by
  mkdir build
    cmake .. \
      -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android34-clang++ \
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-I/home/ripper/android-ndk/android-ndk-r27c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include" \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I/home/ripper/android-ndk/android-ndk-r27c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include" \
      -DANDROID_ABI=x86_64 \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-34 \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ripper/sources_pck/android_libs/mysql-connector-cpp \
      -DWITH_SSL=/home/ripper/sources_pck/android_libs/openssl-3.4.0-android/lib/libssl \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF \
      -DWITH_EXAMPLES=OFF \
      -DWITH_JDBC=OFF 
      


and after run make 

        == Extrnal build done
    [  2%] Built target zstd-build
    [  4%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/error.cc.o
    [  5%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/stream.cc.o
    [  6%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/connection_tcpip.cc.o
    [  8%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/socket.cc.o
    [  9%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/diagnostics.cc.o
    [ 10%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/socket_detail.cc.o
    /home/ripper/sources_pck/mysqlcpp/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/foundation/socket_detail.cc:1097:22: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct __res_state'
     1097 |   struct __res_state state {};
          |                      ^
    /home/ripper/sources_pck/mysqlcpp/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/foundation/socket_detail.cc:1097:10: note: forward declaration of '__res_state'
     1097 |   struct __res_state state {};
          |          ^
    1 error generated.
    make[2]: *** [cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/build.make:149: cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/socket_detail.cc.o] Помилка 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1055: cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/all] Помилка 2
    make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Помилка 2

at first stage i need to build it for using to android emulation x86_64
like that way I've already buld OpenSSL and Curl libs and boost lib I've tryed OpenSSL and Curl thay at least can resolv lib version doesnt test deep.

Android does not define that struct. File a bug with the mysql-connector-cpp project.

Or you could add an #elifdef __ANDROID__ that calls the native Android DNS resolution code

you mean that i have to start editing mysqlconnector_cpp source code to adopte android enviroment ?

That is correct, yes. The Android system is not entirely compatible with Linux.
